# how get current text size in css

Tags: css

I'm tring to write a css that for all string that I can put on increase these strings about 3px. I don't know how can I do this, I think something like this:

```
.increaseSize {
getSize()+3px;
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: have you considered using `em` instead?

Comment: If you own the css, you could use something like SASS/LESS which support operations and then generate the css. Otherwise, you'd need to use javascript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would seek a different and much simpler approach.

```css
p.myText {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.increaseSize {
  font-size: 1.5em
}
```

```html
<p class="myText">This is some standard text and <span class="increaseSize">this is a bigger font size text</span></p>
```

This would make any .increaseSize element font size 50% bigger than its parent.

You can use calc() but maybe [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) is a problem. This is a safer solution.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 10):

You can use it like the following example:

```css
div {
  font-size: 1em;
}
span.increase {
  font-size: calc(100% + 3px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello <span class="increase">World</span>
</div>
```

With the `%` unit you can get the actual font size of the element. Now you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ([browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)) to add the `3px` to the current `font-size`.

> You shouldn't calculate the `font-size` yourself for responsive web-design. You can / should use relative units like `em`, `rem` or `%` to achieve responsive `font-size`.

Comment: Note the [browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

As recomended by W3C

> Set Font Size With Em
>   To allow users to resize the text (in the browser menu), many developers use em instead of pixels.
>
> The em size unit is recommended by the W3C.
>
> 1em is equal to the current font size. The default text size in browsers is > 16px. So, the default size of 1em is 16px.
>
> The size can be calculated from pixels to em using this formula: pixels/16=em

Here are some examples

```
h1 {
font-size: 2.5em; /* 40px/16=2.5em */
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.875em; /* 30px/16=1.875em */
}

p {
font-size: 0.875em; /* 14px/16=0.875em */
}
```