# how to get current font-size for item using css

Tags: css, sass

I need to calc font-size using CSS (CurrenSize + px). 
for example:

```
body * {font-size: calc([CurrenSize] + 3px) !important;}
```

I do that in jQuery but not working smoothly, so I'm asking if I can do that in CSS. 
in CSS (this code working, but the 100% make the text very small that why i need the current font size):

```
body * {font-size: calc(100% + 3px) !important;}
```

in js

```
 $("body *").css('font-size','+=3');
```

Comment: what what is the definition of *current font-size* because you will change it and then the new one will become the current font-size? seems a cyclic definition

Comment: i have too many options like:
.item1{font-size:20px}
.item2{font-size:18px}
.item3{font-size:15px} so i want to change font-size of all of them

Comment: seems like an XY problem. You first defined a *bad* CSS that contain a lot of font-sizes and now you are looking for a hacky way to change all of them. I would consider adjusting the CSS file to make the font-size definition easier where you can easily adjust it in one place (considering CSS variable for example, or em unit, etc)

Comment: that means no way to get the current font-size using CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how get current text size in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901499/how-get-current-text-size-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to increase all font-size by 3px all over the page. You would be able to do that in css only if you had define your font-size with em not with px. This way font are realtive to parent and you are able to twick them easily.

So now you just have the option to make the change in all you font-size value I presume. **Or just change your CSS to use variables for font-size**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: The Link Not Found

Comment: Here you are! syntax pb

Answer (score 0):

The “current” font size is `1em` … so you presumably want `calc(1em + 3px)`

(Or maybe `1rem`, depending on whether you want this to multiple for nested child elements, or not.)

Comment: applied to one element it's good, but to all the elemens (considering his selector) each level will increase by 3px since 1em is relative to the value of font-sze

Comment: i have too many options like: .item1{font-size:20px} .item2{font-size:18px} .item3{font-size:15px} so i want to change font-size of all of them

Comment: @user10943992 you can't change it like that, you could if you were using less or sass but here I don't see a solution other changing it for all of them manually.

Comment: In addition, the selector `body *` will not override the selector `.item1`, so the font size for those items will not change. Only those elements that have no font size selected otherwise will. (That is, for example with `<div class="item1">item <em>one</em>.</div>` the `em` will be bigger than the rest of the text in the `div`.)

Answer (score -1):

If your element does not have font-size property, your jQuery code may not work smoothly. Because your element can inherit font-size property from parent elements. 
Try this:

```
let element = document.getElementById("element"));
let computedFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(element).fontSize;
```

and now, you can do this:

```
element.style.fontSize = computedFontSize+=3;
```

Comment: my jQuery  code working, but it's after page already loaded, and visitor see the text jumping
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNwrzY